# Can't get UITextField variable

Tags: ios, objective-c, variables, properties, uitextfield

I'm trying to change the color of some placeholder text, of a UITextField, but i having problems reaching the text field. I've created a property with Referencing Outlets, like this:

```
@property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *usernameField;
```

But can't reach it with either usernameField or _usernameField. What am i missing?

Comment: @synthesize it...then self.usernameField

Comment: it wont allow me to synthesize it

Comment: no need to synthesize. Just check that if you have correctly connected it to the usernameField outlet.

Comment: it got autocreated by drag and dropping from outlets so it should be connected

Comment: if you want to access, nslog it and check for not null.  `NSLog(@"%@",self.usernameField);`

Comment: @AnoopVaidya if he can't access `self.usernameField` then how to log it ???

Comment: i cant nslog it cause it cant find usernameField on self

Comment: show the full code....

Comment: @AnoopVaidya look at his above comment.

Comment: @user2408952 once clean your project then delete derived data then try..

Comment: this is all the code i got for the usernameField. Can't show more cause its 500 lines of code^^

Comment: did a clean+delete derived data, didn't work. Btw after i create the property, in my dealloc i get an error: use of undeclared identifier "_usernameField"

Comment: @user2408952: u r using MRC!!!.. As you said, its not allowing you to synthesize. You must have created the property on some other class and trying to access in other class.

Comment: self.usernameField and _usernameField are same

Comment: ok try to declare it in implementation file, and first check if you bind/wired that properly.

Comment: Did you wired correctly? Check whether self.usernameField is nil or not.

Comment: yes I'm using MRC, this is a really old project. And no its not created in any other file, when using the search it only finds this single thing, with that name.

Comment: i cant check self.usernameField......... thats the thing I'm trying to reach in the first place^^

Comment: Ok if i declare it directly in my .m's interface it works. Why is that?

Comment: Ah sorry, UITextField and it does have placeholder text^^. Edited my question to UITextField.

Comment: @user2408952 first of all relax you self, and then try to do it in implementation file and plus check if there are multiple connections etc in xib file, remove them.

Comment: is your .m file importing the .h file that has the property declaration?

Comment: yes it is importing the .h file cause i got A LOT of other properties and variables i can access.

Comment: yes it works if i do it in my implementation file. No i dont have multiple connections. But why is it working in my implementation but not interface?

Comment: hmmm check that and tell me too :)

Answer (score 3):

If you have a property, do NOT synthesize it. That just complicates things, and is no longer needed in Objective C 2.0.

Don't use _usernameField. That bypasses the property getter/setter and accesses the iVar directly.

Use self.usernameField instead. Until you understand the difference, use the property except in the code of a custom getter/setter or dealloc method.

Comment: I found out that i can reach it if i declare it in my .m's interface but why cant i get it, if i declare it in my .h's interface?

Comment: what iOS are you writing for? you should strong for most everything after iOS 5

Comment: iOS 7 but its a old project created when ios6 what HOT!^^

Answer (score 0):

first you should use self.usernameField and second just make sure you assigned the outlet to the UITextField you need to access it in the Interface Builder.

Answer (score 0):

[image]You can check it. Have you connected the outlet of the textfield in the xib file?

Comment: yes thats how i created the property by drag and drop from outlet

Comment: Go to the xib file select the texfield and drag the line to File's Owner Icon. Just finish.I am giving screen shot for more ease. Thanks

Comment: then it asks me what view i want to attach it to. I guess that would be my main view and after that?